# Identifying two design patterns?

Tags: design-patterns

I've got two approaches to implement handling of classes, and I'm curious if there are design pattern names for these two.

First implementation - self persisting class:

```
Car c;
c.load(1);
c.Model = "Ferrari";
c.Color = "Yellow";
c.drive();
c.save();
```

In this approach the class contains both properties, and methods. It has all it business logic inside the same class, and knows how to load and persist itself.

Is there a design pattern name for this approach?

And the second implementation - a controller agent and a data object;

```
CarAgent carAgent;
Car c = carAgent.load(1);
c.Model = "Ferrari";
c.Color = "Yellow";
carAgent.drive(c);
c = carAgent.save(c);
```

This approach uses two classes. The Car class is a "stupid" datacarrier class with only properties. No business logic in it. All work being done to the Car class is done using a CarAgent. It contains all business logic, but does not have any internal state or properties.

Does this also have a design pattern name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [Active record](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html): *An object that wraps a row in a database table or view, encapsulates the database access, and adds domain logic on that data.*
2. [Repository](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html)<sup>(a)</sup> + [domain object](http://wiki.c2.com/?DomainObject)<sup>(b)</sup>: (a) *Mediates between the domain and data mapping layers using a collection-like interface for accessing domain objects.* (b) *A domain object is a logical container of purely domain information, usually represents a logical entity in the problem domain space*. The behaviorless object may be also a [POCO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object).

It's not 100% accurate because a definitive answer would involve checking your actual code.